# Нахождение количества кроликов с помощью чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: java, числа-фибоначчи

Задача:

> Есть пара кроликов. Она дает приплод (новую пару кроликов) на **третий** месяц, а последующие месяцы - ежемесячно. Дети, достигающие **трех** месяцев, начинают давать приплод. Какое количество кроликов будет через год?

Что не так в данном решении?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int n;
        int sum_fib;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum_fib = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = sum_fib;
            System.out.print(sum_fib + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: это уже третий такой вопрос за сегодня, но уже с кодом :)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял условие задачи, то последовательность количества пар получается такая:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 13, 19, 28, 41, 60
```

Где первое число - количество пар на начало первого месяца, а далее - количество пар в конце каждого месяца, вплоть до 12-го включительно.

Если всё так, и ответом является "120 кроликов" (60 пар), то последовательностью Фибоначчи это не назвать. Однако линейная рекуррентная последовательность тут всё же прослеживается. В частности:

F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-3</sub>

Код для вычисления:

```
final int monthsCount = 12;
int[] counts = new int[monthsCount + 1];
counts[0] = 1;
counts[1] = 1;
counts[2] = 1;
for (int i = 3; i <= monthsCount; i++)
{
    counts[i] = counts[i - 1] + counts[i - 3];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counts));
```

---

В качестве решения "в лоб" и для проверки результатов использовалось такое:

```
private static class Pair
{
    private static final int GET_MONTHS = 3;

    private int monthsCount = 0;

    public Pair inc()
    {
        monthsCount++;
        return (monthsCount >= GET_MONTHS) ? new Pair() : null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    pairs.add(new Pair());
    for (int i = 0; i < monthsCount; i++)
    {
        List<Pair> newPairs = pairs.stream()
                .map(Pair::inc).filter(e -> e != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        pairs.addAll(newPairs);
    }
    System.out.println(pairs.size());
}
```